# Show data in one column

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am working with jQuery datatables. I am executing the following sql statement:

```
SELECT status, internal_id, name, address, city, id FROM `relations`
```

With the option columnDefs I am trying to show the data in a specific column:
columnDefs targets 0 created the column for 'status'
columnDefs targets 1 created the column for 'internal_id'
etc.

Now what I want is I want to show the data for "name", "address" and "city" in one column. In SQL I can realize this by using concat. But this is not what I want. I want define the columns in columnDefs so I will be able to change the style of the data.

Does someone know what I need to change in my jQuery to put the "name", "address" and "city" in one column?

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#employee_grid1').DataTable({
      "bprocessing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
    "url": "response1.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "error": function(){
      $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
    }
      },
      "columnDefs": [ 
    { "targets": 0, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  ' ' + (data == 0 ? '<center ><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : (data == 1 ? '<i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>')) + ' '} },
    { "targets": 1, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  '<center>'+data+'</center>'} },
    { "targets": 2, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  '<table><tr><td>'+data+'</td></tr>'} },
    { "targets": 3, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  '<td>'+data+'</td>'} },
    { "targets": 4, "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { return  '<td>'+data+'</td></table>'} }              
      ]                
    });   
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option and access full data set using third argument `full` to produce cell content using multiple values.

For example:

```
{ 
    "targets": 2, 
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { 
        return  'Name: ' + full[2] + '<br>Address: ' + full[3] + '<br>City: ' + full[4]; 
    } 
},
```